# Unable to run an Andriod app built with VS 2015 + Xamarin

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, visual-studio-emulator

I must be doing something extremely stupid, but I've been trying for several days and I'm at a loss.  No matter what I do, I cannot get a "hello world" app to run on an Android emulator.  I've even tried a clean install of Windows 10, clean install of VS 2015, and applying all updates (Windows, VS, SDK's, Xamarin).  I've tried multiple API emulators (VS and AVD).  I've tried processor settings on the VS emulators. I've tried turning off fast deploy and shared runtimes.

I've had so many different results (Marshmallow emulator hangs, debugger can't connect, app won't deploy) with the different settings.  But in all cases where the app is successfully deployed to the emulator, the app starts and immediately crashes.  The device logs are not particularly helpful (at least to me).

To be more specific:
1. I can create a new Android (blank) solution and can successfully deploy it to VS Kit Kat and Lollipop emulators.  I can do this with both release and debug configurations.
2. When I attempt to run the app by clicking it in the emulator, it flashes the app screen and immediately stops.

My question is twofold: Is anyone else experiencing problems getting very basic Android apps to run with the latest version of VS 2015, VS Andriod Emulators, and Xamarin?  And is there anything I can change in my configuration to resolve this problem?

Here is the build output:

InspectorDebugSession(0): StateChange: Start -> EntryPointBreakpointRegistered
InspectorDebugSession(0): Constructed
Android application is debugging.
01-04 08:07:09.024 I/art     ( 1531): Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
01-04 08:07:09.077 W/monodroid( 1531): Using override path: /data/data/App1.App1/files/.**override**
01-04 08:07:09.077 W/monodroid( 1531): Using override path: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/App1.App1/files/.**override**
01-04 08:07:09.078 W/monodroid( 1531): Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/App1.App1/files/.**override**/libmonosgen-2.0.so
01-04 08:07:09.078 W/monodroid( 1531): Trying to load sgen from: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/App1.App1/files/.**override**/libmonosgen-2.0.so
01-04 08:07:09.078 W/monodroid( 1531): Trying to load sgen from: /data/app/App1.App1-1/lib/x86/libmonosgen-2.0.so
01-04 08:07:09.092 W/monodroid( 1531): Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/App1.App1/files/.**override**/links/libmonosgen-2.0.so
01-04 08:07:09.093 W/monodroid-debug( 1531): Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=127.0.0.1:8815,server=y,embedding=1
01-04 08:07:09.217 W/monodroid-debug( 1531): Accepted stdout connection: 22
01-04 08:07:10.001 D/Mono    ( 1531): Image addref mscorlib[0xacf1a340] -> mscorlib.dll[0xaf98be00]: 1
01-04 08:07:10.001 D/Mono    ( 1531): AOT module 'mscorlib.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/App1.App1-1/lib/x86/libaot-mscorlib.dll.so" not found
01-04 08:07:10.001 D/Mono    ( 1531): AOT module '/Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-x86/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/mscorlib.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/App1.App1-1/lib/x86/libaot-mscorlib.dll.so" not found
01-04 08:07:10.011 D/Mono    ( 1531): Config attempting to parse: 'mscorlib.dll.config'.
01-04 08:07:10.011 D/Mono    ( 1531): Config attempting to parse: '/Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-x86/etc/mono/assemblies/mscorlib/mscorlib.config'.
Could not connect to the debugger.
InspectorDebugSession(0): Disposed
InspectorDebugSession(0): HandleTargetEvent: TargetExited

And here is the emulator device log.  Again thanks in advance for your help.
https://gist.github.com/screed01/8174a81dc5956a94ed2c549e9819b002

Comment: Please read [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how a question should be formulated for your increasing your chances of getting an answer you can use. As it is right now, there are too many different good answers as the question is too broad. You could narrow it down by including the output.

Comment: That's fair and thanks for the comment.  Can you clarify what output would be most helpful?  I would have posted the device log, but it is thousands of lines. My symptoms sound like other questions I've found here.  But I've tried every recommendation with no success. Again, thanks and let me know what I can provide that might help make the question more clear.

Comment: Can you post the application output please?

Comment: @Scott You could create a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) and paste your log there.

Comment: @Demitrian does the output help identify what is wrong with my environment?  Also, is there anything else I can do to get some upvotes on the question?  I thought I had posted a qood question by summarizing all the things I've tried and by not slamming everyone with a huge log. But apparently not...

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I installed VS 2015 but didn't delete the old Xamarin Studio. After deleting XS the new VS builded my apps without loosing connection to the debugger.

If you want to see particular logs af your device you can do:

**FIND ADB**

Go to preferences in VS => SDK location => Android SDK location. Do cd thislocation in the terminal.

Mostly the path is one of those two:

1. cd
   /Users/*USERNAME*/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools
2. cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools

**FILTER LOGS**

You can filter on a log tag with this command.
./adb logcat -s "YOURTAGNAME"

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @robinb.  I've posted the output.  Please let me know if you have any issues accessing the gist.